# Dosnt work examples in Management API --- exeptions

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

[Goals: list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/goals/list)

None of the examples work. Although the client library is installed.

At the same time, Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting works without errors.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/goo/vendor/autoload.php';

$analytics = initializeAnalytics();

$VIEW_ID = "206215735";
$ACCOUNT_ID = '152594033';
$PROPERTY_ID = 'UA-152594033-1';

function initializeAnalytics()
{
    $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/goo/My Project.json';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Bottom table");
    $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
    $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
    $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);

    return $analytics;
}

    $goals = $analytics->management_goals->listManagementGoals($ACCOUNT_ID,$PROPERTY_ID,'~all');
```

> **Result**
>   Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function listManagementGoals() on null in D:\OpenServer\domains\htdg.local\google1.php:30 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\OpenServer\domains\htdg.local\google1.php on line 30

Why errors occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## All of the examples work. You are using the wrong service.

Your code is using the library for the [Google analytics reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/)

```
$analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);
```

Yet you are attempting to use a method which is part of the [google analytics core   reporting api v3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) and the [managment api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/service-php) which is in a different library.

```
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
```

You should probably be following the PHP tutorial for the proper api [Hello Analytics API: PHP quickstart for web applications](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/web-php)

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
$goals = $analytics->management_goals->listManagementGoals($ACCOUNT_ID,$PROPERTY_ID,'~all');
```

Comment: thanks)) I was beginning to understand. but I thought that without OAUTH it is not possible to implement it.

Comment: I sent the team an email about tweaking the documentation to make ti more clear which service needs to created its not your fault the documentation is lacking now that we have two apis.